# IAM poilcy for an user to access Enhanced Monitoring for RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, monitoring

I am trying to create an IAM user that will have least privileges to be able to view enhanced monitoring for a particular RDS database. I have created a ROLE (Enhanced Monitoring) and attached a managed policy to it:'AmazonRDSEnhancedMonitoringRole'. This role is passed to RDS database using the passrole permission. The policy that I am attaching to this IAM user is as below:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
            "rds:*",
            "cloudwatch:GetMetricData",
            "iam:ListRoles",
            "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
            "cloudwatch:DeleteAnomalyDetector",
            "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
            "cloudwatch:DescribeAnomalyDetectors",
            "cloudwatch:ListMetricStreams",
            "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmsForMetric",
            "cloudwatch:ListDashboards",
            "ec2:*",
            "cloudwatch:PutAnomalyDetector",
            "cloudwatch:GetMetricWidgetImage"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:GetRole",
            "iam:PassRole",
            "cloudwatch:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:cloudwatch:*:accountnumber:insight-rule/*",
            "arn:aws:iam::accountnumber:role/Enhanced-Monitoring",
            "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:accountnumber:db:dbidentifier"
        ]


      }
    ]
}
```

As you can see,I have given almost every permission to this user, but still I am getting 'Not Authorized' error on the IAM user RDS dashboard for enhanced monitoring, although cloudwatch logs are displaying normally.

Comment: "role is passed to RDS database using the passrole permission" what does it mean? What exactly did you do?

Comment: I am following this guide (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html) for enhanced monitoring of RDS. Refer to example 2 on this page.

Comment: I don't fully understand where it is goes wrong for you? The User you are using is having passrole right? And you have passes RDS a role containing the AmazonRDSEnhancedMonitoringRole(weird that a policy is called role) policy?
But you cant see the metrics? Or are you not allowed to set enhanced monitoring?
Have you tried to set cloudwatch:* on all resources? To see if that helps?

Comment: I have also tried cloudwatch:* for all resources but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the error by modifying the policy. Since Enhanced Monitoring utilizes CloudWatch logs, I added a read-only cloudwatch logs policy(CloudWatchLogsReadOnlyAccess). This policy is mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/iam-identity-based-access-control-cwl.html) in AWS documentation. I also added a cloudwatch:GetMetricData permission as suggested on the RDS console. The overall policy is also more compact now:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account_number:role/Enhanced-Monitoring"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:*",
                "logs:Describe*",
                "logs:List*",
                "logs:StartQuery",
                "ec2:*",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "logs:StopQuery",
                "logs:TestMetricFilter",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents",
                "logs:Get*",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricData"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The setup is working fine now.

Comment: This answer needs format improvements and the code block should be wrapped with the language tag.